# SVM classification and loading data from txt

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I would like to create an image recognition application where the user will insert an image on a file and the python application will display if the image belongs to class 1=pass or class 2=fail (classification with svm in python 3).

I have used sklearn. What I am trying is to load a txt file (including an array of extracted features and their labels) and then include those data on the svm. Though, I am getting the error below

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0.01982988  0.04777778  0.04508372  0.55393064]'

Could anyone please help?

My code so far is:

```
from pyimagesearch.localbinarypatterns import LocalBinaryPatterns
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC  
from imutils import paths
import argparse
import cv2
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-e", "--testing", required=True, 
help="path to the tesitng images")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())


df = pd.read_csv('train.txt', sep="[;,]", engine='python')
df.head()  
X = df.drop('Class', axis=1)  
y = df['Class'] 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20)  
svclassifier = SVC(kernel='linear')  
svclassifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

And the train.txt file is:

```
Data,Class
[ 0.02713807  0.01802697  0.01690036  0.01501216  0.01466412  0.01638859
  0.0210163   0.02658022  0.03664452  0.05064286  0.06027664  0.06431134
  0.04303673  0.03247764  0.02293602  0.01847688  0.0174582   0.01860664
  0.02576164  0.02296149  0.0582211   0.37246149]
,[fail]
[ 0.03623561  0.05211099  0.02469929  0.0134991   0.01029103  0.00880611
  0.00898548  0.00870684  0.0117465   0.01962223  0.03895351  0.01956952
  0.00972828  0.00704872  0.00656471  0.00689743  0.00854528  0.01128713
  0.02119957  0.05047751  0.05028719  0.57473797]
,[fail]
[ 0.04293871  0.0292026   0.02329546  0.01473342  0.01127858  0.0107691
  0.01203     0.01478981  0.02045828  0.03043333  0.03817313  0.03602836
  0.02284631  0.014719    0.00999932  0.00857384  0.00940592  0.0143105
  0.02862624  0.03424553  0.05910089  0.51404167]
,[pass]
[ 0.0274558   0.02260355  0.0120938   0.00766592  0.00623965  0.00700311
  0.0105109   0.01435633  0.0228327   0.03671535  0.0509835   0.06406992
  0.03382424  0.02283531  0.01455474  0.01196762  0.01238184  0.01560769
  0.02885654  0.03067498  0.07337675  0.47338975]
,[pass]
[ 0.04557506  0.03065541  0.02441537  0.0145579   0.0114853   0.01115224
  0.01330945  0.01539609  0.01776064  0.0216626   0.02218757  0.02153467
  0.01548431  0.01295433  0.01045522  0.0100229   0.01051257  0.01454908
  0.02735121  0.03250603  0.05923302  0.55723903]
,[pass]
```

Comment: From the error it appears that data file `train.txt` is space delimited but you're parsing it as if it were delimited by `;` or `,`.

Comment: thank you @jodag! Changed the delimiter to space and now getting the error "pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 12 fields in line 6, saw 13. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used." is there something wrong with the data format or the delimiter again? I want to take the first as an array and then after the comma to receive the class where the data belong

Comment: It could be something like that, or the text file is malformed. Difficult to say without seeing `train.txt`.

Comment: Train.txt is the one shown below the code. Can you see it in my question?

Comment: Oops just realized that >_< What you've posted is definitely not a csv file and as such probably can't be parsed easily with `read_csv`

Comment: Is there another way to save the features extracted from images on a txt file with their label, in python?

Comment: An easier way would probably be to dump them using pickle or json.

Comment: Json really helped! Though I am having some trouble including an array in json (as the one shown on the train.txt), without including delimiter.